# Need help sending DELETE request with firebase Rest API with Vuex

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuex

I'm trying to delete some information from firebase and having some trouble getting it to work.

What i'm trying to do is have the deleteRequest button delete the data pulled from the fetch link.

This is the button and method

```
<div class="actions">
  <base-button @click="deleteRequest">Delete</base-button>
  </div>

async deleteRequest() {
  await this.$store.dispatch('requests/deleteRequest', {
    email: this.email,
    message: this.message,
    artistId: this.$route.params.id,
  });

async deleteRequest(context, payload) {
    const removeRequest = {
        userEmail: payload.email,
        message: payload.message
    };
    const response = await fetch(`https://find-artist-d3495-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/requests/${payload.artistId}.json`, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        body: JSON.stringify(removeRequest)
    });

    const responseData = response.json();

    if (!response.ok) {
        const error = new Error(responseData.message || 'Failed to send request.');
        throw error;
    }
    context.commit('deleteRequests', removeRequest);
},
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing ?

Comment: You're still sending a `body`, which I intentionally removed in my answer to your previous question about this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69693340. While this is not guaranteed to be the cause of the problem, the database will at best simply ignore that data.